How to improve fps for human pose recognition using openpose
enter code hereDuring the development process of using Openpose for human pose recognition, we found that the video fps was consistently around 10. But when we ran the program again after opening the virtualBox on the computer, the fps unexpectedly changed to 30. May I ask why? In addition, how can we achieve the same effect through code? (Based on python)，
We want to figure out the reason of this situation, and the methods to achieve our goal.
